# Sharepoint Site Pages library SPListItem and SPListItemVersion

Tags: sharepoint

My Site Pages library has versioning enabled.

When I get the SPListItemVersion I receive the current SPListitem (last Published).

How can I get a specific version of an SPListItem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [SPListItemVersionCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversioncollection.aspx)

Then retrieve your listitem and get the versions:

```
SPListItem Item = list.Items.Where(...);
SPListItemVersionCollection VersionCol = list.Versions;
```

Now `VersionCol` contains all Versions of this document and you can iterate over it or do whatever you like:

```
foreach(var ver in VersionCol)
{
    ...
}
```

To the comments: You cannot get a SPListItem out of the version per default, because as you said, the return type is SPListItemVersion. This however resembles a list item, because it still has the crucial properties like [Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitemversion.fields(v=office.15).aspx). 
In your target library, create a new SPListItem with and match the version fields to your new item fields. rinse and repeat.

Comment: Thanks, but iterating over VersionCol would return a SPListItemVersion and what I am looking for is a SPListItem reference. The issue is there is a versioning enabled Page Library, and I have to copy some older version of a Page to a new location/library. But CopyTo method is not available with SPListItemVersion.

Comment: This isn't actually a problem because SPListItemVersion has a property `Field`. You can iterate over the fields, create a new list item in your targetlist und be done with it